# How to export 3DS Max file to .obj with multiple objects?

Tags: export, file-format, 3ds-max

I have a 3DS Max model of an inhaler which is made up of two parts, the actuator and the cap. When I export the file as a .obj file the cap and the actuator are classed as 1 part.

How do I export this as a .obj file that recognises the actuator and the cap as being separate objects?

[image]

Comment: Questions about 3D are really only limited to composition as it pertains to design. Technical questions are off-topic.

Comment: I do not think there is much you can do about how the exporter and any subsequent importer works. Write your own exporter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by converting the source file on this site: https://clara.io/
Object did not separate geometry, but you can give a name to different "OBJ Groups". I advice to you export in FBX format if you want to get different meshes insted just one.

Answer (score 0):

And me I'd want to have you look carefully at your UV islanding, and seeing where you have vertices merged to be *sure* that your separate parts really *are* separate... if they are, `.obj` should support that - but the recent answer suggesting `.fbx` is not incorrect - there are many instances in which you get a lot more data passthrough with `.fbx`.